# cache memory and mapping

Tags: caching, mapping, memory-address

consider a machine with a byte addressable main memory of 64kbytes and a block size of 8 bytes. 256kbytes is to be used with direct mapping.

1) how many bits are there in a main memory address?

2) how is the memory address divided into a tag, line number and byte number?

3) into which lines would bytes with each of the following addresses be stored?

0001 0001 0001 1011

1100 0011 0011 1100

1101 0000 0001 1101

1010 1010 1010 1010

4) if the byte address 0001 1010 0001 1010 is stored in cache. what are the addresses of the other bytes stored along with it in the same line in cache?

5) if the cache is to be used with 2-way set associative mapping instead of direct mapping, how is the structure of the memory address changed?

6) explain the process of fetching the following memory address in the following example;
start of by direct mapping and then with 2-way set associative mapping, in each case you may assume that there is a hit in cache.
0001 0001 0001 1011

I will be very happy if you can give me the explanation with the solutions of the questions above as I am struggling on these questions and with your help, I will get a better understanding.